# Get value from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON data with me and I want to get the value of slug from every child.

The main problem is I don't know how much children will be generated after every time I got new data. In short generation of a child inside the child is dynamic that is not fixed.

So, How can I get the value of slug from every child that is present in JSON data?

Here I write one JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "title": "Bottle",
        "__domenu_params": {},
        "href": "www.products.com",
        "target": "_blank",
        "slug": "/undefined"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Pencils",
        "__domenu_params": {},
        "slug": "/Pencils"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Stationary",
        "__domenu_params": {},
        "slug": "/Stationary"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Pen",
        "__domenu_params": {},
        "slug": "/Pen"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Cable",
        "__domenu_params": {},
        "slug": "/Cable"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Electronics",
        "__domenu_params": {},
        "slug": "/Electronics",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Charger",
                "__domenu_params": {},
                "slug": "/Charger"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Laptop",
                "__domenu_params": {},
                "slug": "/Laptop"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Mobile",
                "__domenu_params": {},
                "slug": "/Mobile",
                "href": "www.electronics.com",
                "target": "_blank",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "title": "Pendrive",
                        "__domenu_params": {},
                        "slug": "/Pendrive",
                        "href": "www.pendrive.com",
                        "target": "_self"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried this code and get the value of slug from this JSON only. What should I do to get for every possible JSON data?

```
let data = [{"id":11,"title":"Bottle","__domenu_params":{},"href":"www.products.com","target":"_blank","slug":"/undefined"},{"id":10,"title":"Pencils","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Pencils"},{"id":9,"title":"Stationary","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Stationary"},{"id":8,"title":"Pen","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Pen"},{"id":7,"title":"Cable","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Cable"},{"id":5,"title":"Electronics","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Electronics","children":[{"id":4,"title":"Charger","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Charger"},{"id":3,"title":"Laptop","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Laptop"},{"id":2,"title":"Mobile","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Mobile","href":"www.electronics.com","target":"_blank","children":[{"id":6,"title":"Pendrive","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Pendrive","href":"www.pendrive.com","target":"_self"}]}]}]


for (let i = 0; i< data.length ; i++) {
    // console.log(data[i]["children"])
    if (data[i]["children"]) {
        console.log("inside")
        for (let j = 0; j < data[i]["children"].length; j++) {
            // console.log(data[i]["children"][j])
            if (data[i]["children"][j]["children"]) {
                console.log(data[i]["children"][j]["children"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: @Cerbrus Now ok?

Comment: Check if the object contains `children` array. If it does, use Recursion to again parse that children array as data.

Comment: @tbking there is a child inside child up to n number of times. So,  How can I count that?

Comment: You don't need to count. That's what recursion is for. Read about it online. Here's an example [fibonacci implemenation in Javascript using recursion and iteration](https://www.gregjs.com/javascript/2016/writing-a-fibonacci-implementation-in-javascript/)

Comment: @tbking I know about recursion but I am totally confused how to apply over here.

Comment: @HarshPatel I submitted an answer showing how you can use Recursion to parse the data. Hope it solves your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Recursion to parse this data easily:

```
let data = [{"id":11,"title":"Bottle","__domenu_params":{},"href":"www.products.com","target":"_blank","slug":"/undefined"},{"id":10,"title":"Pencils","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Pencils"},{"id":9,"title":"Stationary","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Stationary"},{"id":8,"title":"Pen","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Pen"},{"id":7,"title":"Cable","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Cable"},{"id":5,"title":"Electronics","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Electronics","children":[{"id":4,"title":"Charger","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Charger"},{"id":3,"title":"Laptop","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Laptop"},{"id":2,"title":"Mobile","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Mobile","href":"www.electronics.com","target":"_blank","children":[{"id":6,"title":"Pendrive","__domenu_params":{},"slug":"/Pendrive","href":"www.pendrive.com","target":"_self"}]}]}]


function getAllSlugs(categories) {
  // For each category...
  return categories.reduce((slugList, category) => {
    // add the slug for the particular category...
    slugList.push(category.slug);
    // and, check if the category has children...
    if (category.children && category.children.length) {
      // if children are there, call the same function with the
      // children and add the slugs of children
      slugList = slugList.concat(getAllSlugs(category.children));
    }
    return slugList;
  }, []);
}
// Call the function
getAllSlugs(data);
```

Output:

```
[ '/undefined',
  '/Pencils',
  '/Stationary',
  '/Pen',
  '/Cable',
  '/Electronics',
  '/Charger',
  '/Laptop',
  '/Mobile',
  '/Pendrive' ]
```

Hope this helps!